# Keep last x number of logs from file - Linux

Tags: linux, apache, logging

My server is out of disk space completely. I have one really really large log file and I need to save the last 10000 lines of the log file.
I understand there is space with tune2fs however the log file is filling up rather quick and I do not want the space to be used up as this can cause an issue.

Note: The latest logs are important however the 95% of the file is useless information. I am fixing, apache logs were reporting more information than I needed.

I do not want to create a new file and then move the logs back. I want to save the last X number of logs from the file and delete the rest without moving to a new file first.

**Commands** I have used which do not work:

```
cat test | tail -10000 | tee test

tail -n 10000 test | tee test

tail -n 10000 test > test
```

I haven't tried `sed` yet, this may work?

Please, any suggestions would be appreciated. At this time I am testing on a separate document file because I have accidentally deleted all of the logs now. So far all commands have failed.
Thanks for the help

Additional Note: This is now purely hypothetically as I have accidentally destroyed my file using one of the commands above.

Comment: Why are you not using logrotate to handle this?

Comment: Mistake on my behalf, I was playing about with logrotate recently and the configuration settings are slightly wrong. I have fixed all issues now and it should not happen again. Just want to know what I did wrong and how to do it if it ever happened again

Comment: That last command will do that to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the file in place by using `dd` to rewind
the seek pointer back to the start of the file on output. Eg 
to keep the last 5 lines of /tmp/a in place:

```
$ len=$(tail -5 /tmp/a | wc -c)
$ tail -5 /tmp/a | dd conv=notrunc of=/tmp/a
$ truncate -s $len /tmp/a
```

Here is an example test:

```
$ cat /var/log/messages >/tmp/a
$ wc -l /tmp/a
13160 /tmp/a
$ head -1 /tmp/a
Sep  2 03:34:11 pure-ftpd: [INFO] Timeout (no operation for 1800 seconds)
$ len=$(tail -5 /tmp/a | wc -c)
$ tail -5 /tmp/a | dd conv=notrunc of=/tmp/a ; truncate -s $len /tmp/a
$ wc -l /tmp/a
5 /tmp/a
$ cat /tmp/a
Sep  9 17:05:02 systemd: Started Session 7209 of user meuh.
Sep  9 17:10:01 systemd: Starting Session 7210 of user meuh.
Sep  9 17:10:01 systemd: Started Session 7210 of user meuh.
Sep  9 17:15:01 systemd: Starting Session 7211 of user meuh.
Sep  9 17:15:01 systemd: Started Session 7211 of user meuh.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
 tail -n 10 +K FILENAME
```

This will print 10k last lines of FILENAME. 
You can save that last lines to another file, then delete original large FILENAME file, by typing

```
tail -n 10 +K FILENAME > NEW_FILENAME && rm FILENAME
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer unfortunately this way creates a new file before deleting the old one. If I have 0kb free space then it would not be able to create the NEW_FILENAME before deleting FILENAME

Answer (score 0):

If your system is using systemd you use the `journalctl` command to filter out just the messages you need.

Some examples:

Show only log messages from the httpd daemon:

```
journalctl -u httpd.service
```

Show only log messages from the httpd daemon for a give time frame:

```
journalctl -u httpd.service --since today
journalctl --since="2015-09-21 09:00:00" --until="2015-09-22 13:59:59"
```

Show the last 100 loglines (for everything/httpd/a given pid):

```
journalctl -n 100
journalctl -u httpd.service -n 100
journalctl _PID=2100 -n 100
```

You can save the output of all commands to a file log.txt by appending `> log.txt` eg. `journalctl -u httpd.service --since today > log.txt`

At some distros it might be necessary to prefix the command with `sudo` if the journal is not persisted or your user is not in the `systemd-journal` group.